# Update ENUM value with PreparedStatement java PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, enums, prepared-statement

I have an SQL Enum:

```
CREATE TYPE position as ENUM ('G','W','D');
```

And I need to update this value using java PreparedStatement. I tried to do it in this way:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE players 
SET position = ? WHERE id = 1");

ps.setString(1, "W");
```

But I get an **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException**: ERROR: syntax error at or near "position".

I also tried `position = ?::position` or `position = CAST(? AS position)` but I always get the same error. 
Please help me to manage with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to quote the name of your enum when you cast:

```
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("update players set position = ?::\"position\" where id = 1");
```

The syntax error is happening because POSITION is a keyword. Wrapping it in double quotes forces postgres to parse it as an identifier.

Probably a good idea to use a different name for the enum.

Answer (score 1):

This is because position is a function already declared in Postgres. Please use any different name. No casting is required.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
ps.setObject(1, "W", Types.OTHER);
```